# How to watch two events and do something after they?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu, and for each li tag I have a different submenu, but for all, I use the same tag for create a background. When a submenu is open and I go for other submenu, all the others hides themselves and the next menu opens. I want that, if I open a submenu and I go to put my mouse point on other li tag, instead of hiding everything, just change the content.

[My website now](http://nomadesdigitais.com)

I just need help for do something like:

```
if $('.active').mouseleave() && $('active').next().mouseenter() {
    // do something cool here
}
```

And the effects and more I do.

Comment: I dont understand what you want.. your menu seems to work fine.

Comment: I want when I put my mouse on the <li and after I put my mouse on the next <li >, he kept the background but change only the content. For this, I was thinking in use that code in the question

Comment: Which background do you refer to? Your question is really poorly worded. Can you add some specifics?

Answer (score 0):

maybe so:

```
$('.active').on('mouseleave', '', {}, function() {
   $(this).attr('mouse', 'leave');
});

$('.active').on('mouseenter', '', {}, function() {
   $(this).attr('mouse', 'enter');
   if($(this).prev('.active').attr('mouse') == 'leave') {
      console.log('gotcha');
   }
});
```